# From prime to prime by squaring the digits

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

I took prime $131$, squared digits of it and wrote them in natural order as they appear, from left to right, and obtained $191$, then I obtained $1811$ by the same procedure, and then $16411$ and then $1361611$, and $131,191,1811,16411$ are primes and $1361611$ is not.

To illustrate how to arrive at the next number in sequence from previous one, take, for example, $16411$.

We have: $1^2=1$ and $6^2=36$ and $4^2=16$ and $1^2=1$ and $1^2=1$ so we obtain $1361611$ from $16411$.

> Can we generate in this way as large a number of different (to avoid loops like one that starts with $11$) primes as we want? Or there is/are some law/laws that do not allow that?

Comment: There may be some elegant proof to this (and I would love it if there were), but I wouldn't hold my breath. Thing is, your procedure is deeply rooted in base ten. And there is no simple way to interleave base ten dependent stuff with base independent stuff like primeness. That being said, it's an interesting question.

Comment: With start $11$ , we land in an infinite loop, but this only gives one prime. Same with $101$

Comment: @Peter Made an edit, to avoid trivialities.

Comment: $131$ is the smallest number giving $4$ primes , $2111$ the smallest number giving $5$ primes.

Comment: $\color\red {12\ 815\ 137}$ gives $6$ primes.

Comment: According to my calculation, $7$ (or more) primes don't appear upto $3\cdot 10^8$

Comment: Um ... but you noticed that 1361611 wasn't prime.  So I don't understand.  131 fails.  So why would you assume any number would succeed.  Why should this versus any other procedure (say squaring and adding 1) produce primes?

Comment: According to my furhter calculation , $7$ or more primes do not occur upto $4.6\cdot 10^9$.

Comment: @Peter Do you think that there is some upper bound for this question?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Hard to say indeed. On the one hand, an arbitary number of primes of that form appearing in row in one such sequence seems to be unlikely. But If we cannot find forced common factors, the possibility cannot be ruled out. However, I don't think that we ever find long sequences. $10$ primes would be truely sensational.

Comment: @Peter DId you do the research for those numbers that generate 4 or 5 or 6 primes about smallest prime factors of numbers that are composites after 5 or 6 or 7 steps?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen No, but I could rerun my program , if you are interested.

Comment: @Peter Yes I am a little bit. Then, if you think that is smart enough, you can turn all the details of your research into an answer, not of the question, but still maybe an useful answer. It could really be an interesting answer, if armed with enough details.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. This question of mine looks recreational enough to maybe have such an answer that you want, It could be that someone will take care of all the details.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen I noticed (by searching long sequences without small prime factors) that usually, the number of digits "explodes", drastically decreasing the chance of very long sequences.

Comment: @Peter Why do you think that "big" increase in the number of digits in this way will generally decrease the chance of next number being prime? Because of the prime number theorem?

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen Yes, this is no disproof but it makes me sceptical.

Comment: @Peter I am not sceptical because of the prime number theorem but because we build larger numbers only by squaring ten possible numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), so the "freedom of building next numbers in sequences from previous ones"  is not really a big freedom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70080/discussion-between-peter-and-antoine-pal-adeen).

Comment: (FYI) Using Sage I checked all primes up to the $12$-digit prime $103723971119$, which produces a chain of length $7$ and is the least prime that produces a chain longer than $6$.

Answer (score -2):

Please do not downvote !

I just want to show my program and the numbers upto $150\cdot 10^6$ giving $5$ or $6$ primes. I hope that someone can verify whether my program is actually correct.

```
? t=0;m=0;while(t<7,m=nextprime(m+1);gef=0;t=0;n=m;while((isprime(n,2)==1)*(gef=
=0),d=digits(n);s=0;for(j=1,length(d),if(d[j]>0,s=s*10^length(digits(d[j]^2))+d[
j]^2);if(d[j]==0,s=s*10));if(n==s,gef=1);n=s;t=t+1);if(t>=5,print(m,"  ",t)));pr
int(m,"  ",t)
2111  5
2179223  5
3012137  5
5103611  5
5320309  5
6018713  5
6033593  5
6096907  5
7868621  5
8126617  5
10033109  5
11119001  5
12139483  5
12815137  6
13622461  5
18901391  5
18991061  5
21806593  5
22024993  5
24414217  5
27073433  5
30652483  5
37102529  5
38024237  5
38318381  5
42991061  5
44402023  5
47240177  5
48413147  5
50507983  5
56415659  5
57493621  5
70284323  5
70882139  5
71164913  5
81266123  5
82376953  5
84304607  5
88399933  5
90194861  5
97372019  5
100544033  5
107802001  5
110006453  5
110084281  5
111944939  5
114471263  6
115405699  5
115629091  5
118326457  5
120451927  5
124656913  5
126060271  5
126651227  5
127991333  5
128151323  6
130147313  5
139151029  5
141296509  5
143451823  5
144418661  6
152451113  5
  ***   at top-level: ...+1);gef=0;t=0;n=m;while((isprime(n,2)==1)*(ge
  ***                                             ^--------------------
  *** isprime: user interrupt after 26min, 11,531 ms
  ***   Break loop: <Return> to continue; 'break' to go back to GP prompt
break>
?
```

Comment: I've recently found it especially helpful to always state the programming language used in a piece of presented code.  This can save others the trouble of guessing (looks like GP to me, but not everyone is as familiar). Cheers!

Comment: @Peter - FYI, my own Sage program produces this same list. Also, starting with the prime $5064291151$ (which generates a chain of $6$ primes), I tested the next $1.26\,10^9$ primes without finding any that generate a chain of $7$ primes. In this range of primes, $33861214627$ is the largest that produces a chain of length $6$. (I started at $5064291151$ because I thought someone posted that they'd tested up to that number and had found no chains of length $7$. Now I can't find that posting, though.)

Comment: The program is PARI(/GP (sorry, thought I have already mentioned it)

Comment: @r.e.s. My search limit was $4.6\cdot 10^9$. But it would be nice if you double-checked the whole range upto $5\cdot 10^9$ (which is a smaller range than that you checked)

Comment: Okay ... I've now checked all primes up to $36043180087\ \ (\approx 3.6\, 10^{10})$, with the result that none of them produce a chain of length greater than $6$.

Comment: ***Surprise!*** The $12$-digit prime $103723971119$ produces a chain of length $7$ and is the least prime that produces a chain longer than $6$. (Among the primes less than this, there are $67$ that produce chains of length $6$.)

Comment: @r.e.s. Well done!  Are the primes in the chain proven primes or probable primes ?

Comment: I'm running Sage with the arithmetic proof flag set to True, so according to the [documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/rings/integer.html), the is_prime() function (which I'm using) is doing a provable primality test.

Comment: @r.e.s. And how large is the largest prime in this chain ?

Comment: It has $102$ digits.